# Declaring methods extern in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, linker

I already have a few procedures intending to be used as C++ methods written in Assembly (with proper calling convention and name mangling). However, when I try to use them

```
class Foo {
    extern void foo();
}
```

I get "invalid storage class for a class member." How can I properly externally define a C++ method?

One workaround is to generate a thunk defining the method which simply calls the assembly version, using inline assembly to support the thiscall convention. In fact, I already have code to generate these. However, I'd really like to get this more direct method working.

Comment: Did you try just leaving off the `extern`?

Comment: You can probably use `extern "C" void foo();` which will use C's calling conventions (no name mangling/decoration). You should be able to call those from assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave off the extern. Functions are externally visible by default.

Comment: You might want to make them public though.  Or you can switch to struct.

Comment: Whether it's public or not shouldn't make a difference in linkage. That only matters to the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  It was more just a general observation.